# how to Turn off WAL in hbase,

Tags: python, performance, hadoop, hbase, database-performance

I need to increase performance for read/write operation in Hbase setup, in my setup no need of WAL is turned on, please tell me how to turnoff WAL

Please give me ur suggestions/tips.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://hbase.apache.org/book/perf.writing.html) it the HBase documentation on how to turn on WAL off.

Comment: thanks for this.@Praveen Sripati is there any xml file for turn off WAL off,because i'm python to insert and remove data into hbase,

Answer (score 0):

You can use HBase [thrift API](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi)

When you have a list of mutations you can specify not to write to WAL

```
struct Mutation {
  1:bool isDelete = 0,
  2:Text column,
  3:Text value,
  4:bool writeToWAL = 1
}
```

Once you've [generated a thirft client](http://whynosql.com/using-thrift-python-client-with-hbase/)
you can

```
from thrift.transport.TSocket import TSocket
from thrift.transport.TTransport import TBufferedTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from hbase import Hbase 

transport = TBufferedTransport(TSocket('localhost', 9090))
transport.open()
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
client = Hbase.Client(protocol)
table_name = 'theTable'
row_key = 'test_row1'
colfamily = 'test_colfamily1'
qualifier = 'test_col1'
fullyqualied = ('%s:%s' % (colfamily, qualifier))
value = 'some value'
client.mutateRow(table_name, row_key, [Mutation(column=fullyqualified, value=value,writeToWAL=false)], {})
```

Comment: I'm using python library happybase for insertion and deletion, i want to turn off WAL for all insertion, is there any other way like modifing XML file in hbase(config file).please give ur suggestion thanks advance....@Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz

Comment: I don't know of a way to turn off WAL completely in HBase (that isn't to say that there isn't). In any event the source for happybase is on git https://github.com/wbolster/happybase/tree/happybase-0.6 so you can just add the noWAL support